# Getting Resources$NotFoundException in Webview of Android 8 (Oreo)

Tags: android, webview, android-8.0-oreo

I am loading the URL of a website in WebView of my app. This website takes the basic details of a user. **I am loading the WebView in activity.** But when users of Android 8 clicks on the drop down of a website then the app throws below error. Please note that this WebView works perfectly on Android 7.1 or below. It only throws error in Android 8.0.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: <Package Name>, PID: 9392
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:195)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2133)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1142)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:416)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:407)
at org.chromium.content.browser.input.SelectPopupAdapter.getView(SelectPopupAdapter.java:53)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2372)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1408)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1315)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
at com.android.internal.widget.AlertDialogLayout.tryOnMeasure(AlertDialogLayout.java:144)
at com.android.internal.widget.AlertDialogLayout.onMeasure(AlertDialogLayout.java:69)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2410)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1471)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1751)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Code :

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
} else {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}

WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(<URL Here>);

  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {        
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });
```

Layout File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/pay_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/webview_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Payment"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where is dropdown? Can you show your layout!

Comment: Hi @MeosCoder, the drop down is in the website which works perfectly on android 7.1 or below

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check it.

Comment: Can you show your url?

Comment: I checked in android virtual 8.0 and error didn't occur

Comment: Please click on the drop down

Comment: Hey @MeosCoder thanks! I got what I want. I was targeting 23. When I changed it to 26 it works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Finally it worked for me!**

Before my project has compileSdkVersion to 23 and com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0. After changing **compileSdkVersion to 26** and **com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0** in build.gradle (app) it starts working on Android Oreo.

Comment: thank you! I have been for hours trying to find out the solution for that same error that I was getting when trying to open a dropdown inside a webview.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Mayur_Thakur's answer, in my case, i was using androidx and all i did was to update all gradle implementations to the latest. and i changed my compileSDK version to 29 as per the current minimum for November onward per playstore guidelines. And it worked fine for me.