# Android x App is crashing when click on SELECT tag in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-9.0-pie

I have migrate to android x every thing is working fine but In `webview` when is click on **SELECT** tag app is crashing in android 9 , its working fine in android 6 or lower devices.
before migrate its working fine.
 This is my error log

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:228)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2170)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1170)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:424)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:415)
    at ms2.getView(PG:2)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3219)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1451)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1358)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
    at com.android.internal.widget.AlertDialogLayout.tryOnMeasure(AlertDialogLayout.java:144)
    at com.android.internal.widget.AlertDialogLayout.onMeasure(AlertDialogLayout.java:69)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:992)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3301)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2330)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1888)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8511)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

App gradle

```
ext {
 gms = "17.0.0"
 supportLibraryVersion = '1.0.0'
 appCompatVersion = '1.1.0'
 googlePlayServiceVersion = '17.0.0'
 firebaseCore = '17.2.1'
 firebaseMessaging = '20.1.0'
}

 dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.8.0'
 implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appCompatVersion"
 implementation "androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:$supportLibraryVersion"
 implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$googlePlayServiceVersion"
 implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$googlePlayServiceVersion"
 implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit"
 implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttpInterceptor"
 implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:$supportLibraryVersion"
 implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"
 implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebaseCore"
 implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebaseMessaging"
 implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$appCompatVersion"
}
```

```
@SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "AddJavascriptInterface", "JavascriptInterface"})
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    homeActivity.setBackPressListener(this);
    final View mParentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mfa_webview,
            container, false);
    webview = (WebView) mParentView.findViewById(R.id.webviewfrag);
    webViewForCreateSession = (WebView) mParentView.findViewById(R.id.webViewSession);
    webViewForCreateSession.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
    webview.setWebViewClient(new ChildBrowserClient());
    enableWebSettings(webview);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
        webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(),
                "HTMLOUT");
    } else {
        webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterfaceBelow17(),
                "HTMLOUT");
    }

    webview.requestFocus();
    return mParentView;
}
```

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46208138/9030938) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49606995/9030938) but did't get any solution.

Comment: can you share the relevant source code as well?

Comment: @harshithdwivedi Check post updated

Comment: Where's the code where you define click on the select tag?

Comment: @harshithdwivedi its a web page click  not a native code ,